# Python NaN problems

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nan

I'm reading sets of coordinates in from a CSV that was generated from a pandas dataframe. The coordinates sets weren't all the same length, so they were padded with NaNs. Here's the code that I'm trying to get to work:

```
df=pd.read_csv('contours_20150210.csv') # reading in the dataframe and xy coordinates
c131x=np.asarray(df["contour_131_x"])
c131y=np.asarray(df["contour_131_y"])
c193x=np.asarray(df["contour_193_x"])
c193y=np.asarray(df["contour_193_y"])
c211x=np.asarray(df["contour_211_x"])
c211y=np.asarray(df["contour_211_y"])

nn_193_211=[]

dist_193_211 = distance_matrix(c193,c211) #Computing the distances between all the sets of coordinates

for i in range(len(dist_193_211[:][1])):
    nn_193_211.append([np.where(dist_193_211[i] == np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i]))[0][0],np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i])]) 
# I am looking for the nearest neighbors, both the value of the distance between them and which value that is in the list of coordinates
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error when the for loop reaches the nans, even though I'm using `np.nanmin`.

```
/tmp/ipykernel_3022/578260609.py:2: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered
  nn_193_211.append([np.where(dist_193_211[i] == np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i]))[0][0],np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i])])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3022/578260609.py in <module>
      1 for i in range(len(dist_193_211[:][1])):
----> 2     nn_193_211.append([np.where(dist_193_211[i] == np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i]))[0][0],np.nanmin(dist_193_211[i])])
      3 print(nn_193_211[0:100])
      4 #print(np.max(nn_193_211),np.min(nn_193_211))

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I decided I would just truncate the padding nans (they're the only nans in the array, there's no missing data elsewhere). So I read up on nans in Python and ran the following tests:

```
print('c131x: ',c131x)
print('np.nan is np.nan:',np.nan is np.nan)
print('c131x[-1] is np.nan:',c131x[-1] is np.nan)

print(np.where(np.vectorize(c131x) is np.nan))
print(np.where(np.vectorize(c131y) is np.nan))
print(np.where(np.vectorize(c193x) is np.nan))
print(np.where(np.vectorize(c193y) is np.nan))
print(np.where(np.vectorize(c211x) is np.nan))
print(np.where(np.vectorize(c211y) is np.nan))
```

This is the output:

```
c131x:  [-202.79993465 -202.49993494 -202.19993523 ...           nan           nan
           nan]
np.nan is np.nan: True
c131x[-1] is np.nan: False
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

It's my understanding that both `np.nan is np.nan` and `c131x[-1] is np.nan` should be returning `True`: am I missing something? I can't slice the array if I can't identify where the nans are.

Comment: Use `np.isnan(np.vectorize(c131x))` instead. Any comparison with `np.nan` will be False.

Comment: Is that right? I know that nothing `== np.nan`, including `np.nan`, but I thought `is` was still a valid way to test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueBuffalo73's suggestion gave me an error about unsafe casting; however, I was inspired by the suggestion and tried

`c131x=c131x[:np.where(np.isnan(c131x))[0][0]]`

which did work. I now have truncated coordinate arrays.

Comment: You can remove the `== True` part of the expression. `np.isnan` already returns boolean values.